# C# Path.GetTempFileName() with specific path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a temp file and get its path with this code:

```
    public ActionResult Comp(string Link)
    {
        var sv = Server.MapPath(Link);

            int quality = 45;
            string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            System.IO.File.Copy(sv, tempFile, true);
            using (var myBitmap = Image.FromFile(tempFile))
            {
                ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
                Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
                EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, quality);
                EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
                myBitmap.Save(sv, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
            }

            System.IO.File.Delete(tempFile);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The Comp function using in image compressor. It get string file path, creating a tmp file in `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp` by getted image in `Link`, nextly encodede tmp file with setted quality and set tmp file to getted image, finally deleting tmp file. But this code create and delete a temp file in `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp`. I want to create temp file in a specific path because my server not get permission this path. So this code may be as follow:

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName("/Content/temp/");
//It gets error that do not have overload method of GetTempFileName
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random named text file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270584/how-to-generate-a-random-named-text-file-in-c)

Comment: Edited question no random file name.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your code above is currently calling `GetRandomFileName()`, not `GetTempFileName()`

Comment: The edit hasn't made the question any clearer. The file name returned by `GetTempFileName()` is, for all intents and purposes, random. It is not as "random" as the one returned by `GetRandomFileName()`, but it's not easily predicted either. If you don't want a random file name, what _do_ you want? "Not random" implies some predictable algorithm; what algorithm are you looking for?

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I wrote it wrong, it is not `GetRandomFileName()`. It is `GetTempFileName()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is that the code does not have permissions in the temp folder, how about simply creating a unique file name in a folder the code does have permissions to?  The function `Path.GetRandomFileName()` will do so.  It does not create the file for you, it just create a random file name that you can use in a folder of your choice. To be extra safe, you can first check if the file already exists, but that will be highly unlikely.

Example:

```
String folderPathThatYouCanWriteTo = "Your Writable Path here";
String fullFilePath = null;
do
{
    fullFilePath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", folderPathThatYouCanWriteTo, Path.GetRandomFileName());
} while (File.Exists(fullFilePath));

//Now you can use fullFilePath
etc.
```

Comment: Edited question I do not want to random file name.

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to use `GetRandomFileName()`?  Even `GetTempFileName()` returns a quasi random file name insofar as it has to return a unique file name.  But `GetTempFileName` is tied to the temporary directory.  My approach let's you generate a file that is guaranted to be unique in a directory of your choice. It sounded like that was what you wanted?

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I wrote it wrong, it is not GetRandomFileName(). It is GetTempFileName()

Comment: I figured.  Question, though.  Why not use GetRandomFileName(), since GetTempFileName does not do what you want?

Comment: Because `GetRandomFileName()` no create a file. If you examine my edited question, `string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();` this code create a temp file in the Temp folder, `System.IO.File.Copy(sv, tempFile, true);` this code override old file from temp file, nextly setting low quality and encoding, finally `System.IO.File.Delete(tempFile);` this code deleting temp file.

Comment: Well you can do `System.IO.File.Copy(sv, fullFilePath, true);` using my example and then delete it `System.IO.File.Delete(fullFilePath);`.  But you need to do whatever you think works best for you.  Have a good night!